# window.open() method works in android app but not in windows phone app

Tags: jquery, windows, cordova

```js
var ref = window.open(encodeURI("anyurl"), '_blank', "location=no");
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function (event) {
        if (event.url.match("mobile/close")) {
            ref.close();
        }
    });
```

I use this code in my app and build the app for both android and windows using Adobe Phonegap but the problem arises here is the code works fine for android but in windows case, link does,nt open. so please help me solve this.  Thank U

Comment: Encoding an entire URL to open makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Maybe it's not supported for Mobile IE. Look at the bottom in the link about comatibility

Answer (score 0):

Try install InAppBrowser plugin:

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser

and then try open new window using this pice of code:

In deviceReady event you must replace original window.open by:

```
window.open = cordova.InAppBrowser.open;
```

Or determine address by doing :

```
var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://apache.org', '_blank', 'location=yes');
```

More info about using this plugin you will find in documentation.